# Send current date to datetime mysql field from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

Ok, sorry for the badly worded question. Clearly I am not experienced and I do not want to waste anyone's time.

I have a C# application, I need to update the last_modified field
   with DateTime.Now, but I keep getting formatting error.

I am using MVC, C# and I connected an existing MySQL database.

The model I have is 
        public partial class user
        {
         public int id_user { get; set; }
         public string first_name { get; set; }
         public DateTime last_modified { get; set; }
        }

I have a method to update the values

```
    public void Update(user aUser)
    {
    user target = db.users.Find(aUser.id_user)
    if (target != null)
                {
                    target.id_user = aUser.id_user;
                    target.first_name = aUser.first_name;
                    target.last_modified = DateTime.Now;
                 }
    }
```

Comment: Dates have no format. *DON'T* convert the date to a string. Use parameterized queries and pass the datetime value as a date-typed parameter.

Comment: What error?  Which line throws the error?  What are the values when that happens?  It seems *very unlikely* that the line of code you're showing is producing a format error.  Why are you involving string formatting at all?

Comment: I have a field Datetime on the database. I am updating this field, but mysql date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. 
When I send the data back to the database directly from DateTime.Now, I get an error that says the data is not valid as the format is dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @lonelySiren I'll repeat it. Dates have no format at all. They are binary values. *Strings* do. Just *don't* use strings when you want to pass dates. Don't use string concatenation either. Use parameterized queries. Google for `Bobby Tables` to understand why. String concatenation doesn't only result in conversion errors, it's what allows SQL injection attacks to happen

Comment: @lonelySiren: The code in your question has *no* interaction with any database.  All this *single line of code* does is convert a `DateTime` value to a `string` value.  And it does this successfully.  Start examining the *actual problem* instead of assuming this line of code has anything to do with it.

Comment: @lonelySiren if you don't know what parameterized queries are, post your query code so someone can fix it

Comment: Ok, sorry for the badly worded question. Clearly I am not experienced and I do not want to waste anyone's time.
I am using MVC, C# and I connected a MySQM database. 
The model is 
public int id_user { get; set; }
public string first_name { get; set; }
public DateTime last_modified { get; set; }

I am not using parameterized queries, but I will look into this. 

 public void Update(UserViewModel aUser,

Comment: @lonelySiren what you posted in the comments has nothing to do with querying either. If you have a problem with a query, post the *query* and the code that executes the query

Comment: @lonelySiren: `"I am not using parameterized queries"` - (1) You should.  (2) Are you using *any queries at all*?  Are you interacting with a database *in any way*?  Because so far you've been unable to show any code which has anything to do with a database.  We can appreciate that you're a beginner, but unless you can actually demonstrate the problem there's nothing we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following statement in a parameterized query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ID=?;
```